# how to send link in theme my login plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have used theme my login plugin in wordpress. I want to send reset password link mail. So have written code like this:

```
    $message = __( 'Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'To reset your password, visit the following address:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message1 = "<a href='" . site_url() . "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=".  rawurlencode( $user_login ) . "'>" . site_url() . "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=".  rawurlencode( $user_login ). "</a>" ;

    $message .= $message1;
```

but I received text instead of link. so what should I have to do to solve this issue?

Comment: change your mailprogram setting from plaintext to HTML?

Comment: where i have to changed that setting in theme my login plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I have just define one variable like this

```
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and added this variable into wp_mail() function. So it is solved. 
Thank you.